# Unexpected output when using a ternary operator and final variable

Tags: java, final, ternary-operator

Consider this code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int z1 = 0;
    final int z2 = 0;
    System.out.println(false ? z1 : 'X');
    System.out.println(false ? z2 : 'X');
}
```

When running this code, I would expect to see two `X` in your console. However, the real output is:

> 88
>   X

If we take a look at the [Java specifications regarding the ternary operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25), we found that

> If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

So the first output considers the `'X'` char as an `int`, that's why it prints `88`.

However, I am not sure to understand why the use of `final` changes the behavior for the second output.

Comment: Just as a side point, this is the second time today where I've seen someone effectively assume that what *they* expect to see is what everyone *else* expects to see. I think it would be more appropriate to say, "When running this code, I expected to see..."

Comment: @Jon, you are right. Question edited.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/0zGzPygyJSU

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the second case, `z2` counts as a [constant expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313), because it's a final variable of type `int`.

From [section 4.12.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#10931):

> We call a variable, of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28) a constant variable. Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility (§13.1, §13.4.9) and definite assignment (§16).

[Section 15.28](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313) includes "constant variables" in the set of items which can be used to form a constant expression.

`z1` is *not* a final variable (even though nothing else assigns a value to it) so it's not a constant variable, and thus not a constant expression - so the paragraph you quoted from the spec doesn't apply.