# Ternary operator returns an unexpected output

Tags: java, ternary

This subject is already asked but I didn't understand it.
You'll find my program below. When I run this program it prints X and 88. When I remove do the declaration of int i = 0 it returns X and X. I found some explanations here : [Unexpected output when using a ternary operator and final variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711431/unexpected-output-when-using-a-ternary-operator-and-final-variable) but i didn't understand it so much. I don't understand why this program returns X and 88 instead of X and X.

```
public class Ternary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char x = 'X';
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(true  ? x : 0);
        System.out.println(false ? i : x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please read the rules of `ternary operator` here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

1st one is result of `If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression  of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.`  **T being type char in this case and constant expression being 0**

so the output is of type char which is **x**

---

2nd one is case for `Otherwise, binary numeric promotion  is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.`

read about binary numeric promotion here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

**last case of point 2 applies here** `Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.` and converting char to int gives its ascii value which is **88**

and hence the output is 88